# We need a site slogan

Tags: discussion

We should have a site slogan, something on topic, humorous and catchy. This could be included in all promotional ventures, e-mail/forum signatures, etc.

There are a ton of sites using really, really bad software for Q&A. We've got something better, we have the talent needed to effectively and accurately answer questions, and we need to save people from the Soviet era of forums (note, nothing against them for discussions, but we deal with questions here).

But, we need to get them here first. My idea is, these slogans can be used on the banners and other promotional tools, as appropriate.

Comment: You should probably separate your suggestion into an answer of its own. It's hard to vote on it separately when its part of the question.

Comment: @Robert - done.

Answer (score 12):

I'll see your 404 and raise you 500.

Poker reference, but I thought it was funny.

Comment: This is tooo long.

Comment: I love it, although I'm not sure it will fit well if we go with a site name like "Response 200". @s_ruchit: How is it too long, is there some unspoken character limit? (Also, the suggestions you posted are barely shorter.)

Answer (score 8):

All your HTML are belong to us !

Comment: I love it because its the most relevant ihazcheeseburger-ism.

Answer (score 6):

"Don't eat my cookies!"

Answer (score 5):

Another slogan that come to my mind.

> You POST, all GET.

or,

> You PUT, all GET.

Comment: PUT? I'm a webmaster, not an **FTPmaster**...

Answer (score 4):

Don't get rooted

(it's a security joke, and in some parts of the world a double entendre)

Comment: Seems like it would me more appropriate on Server Fault, to be honest.

Comment: Probably. Or a security-related site.

Answer (score 4):

Why not, "Have you tried using jQuery?" (Sorry, I couldn't resist). ;-)

Comment: Ooh, I like that too! Or maybe a variation: "Because jQuery can't fix EVERYTHING!"

Comment: "we knowz when jQuery=FAIL"

Answer (score 3):

How about

*Be the master of your domain*

or some variation.

- [Master the web, before the web becomes your master](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mystery_Men)?
- Master your domain, master the world!
- Master your domain, professionally, using the web and stuff?
- Masterfully mastering the web since 2010?

Comment: http://www.he-man.org/ would own our SEO on that one...

Answer (score 3):

Your web referrence.

Comment: Assuming that your misspelling is intentional, this is very clever! (For the uninitiated: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer)

Answer (score 2):

```
GET / HTTP/1.1

HTTP/1.1 200 Success
```

Just an idea I'm throwing out there...

Answer (score 2):

> More than just SEO

Although to be honest, I think 90% of the questions on here are regarding SEO.

Comment: Not quite .. and the 'king' topic is temporal at best, we're just getting started. I like this, +1.

Answer (score 2):

Teh internets: RTFM :)

Answer (score 1):

How about.

Source Control

Answer (score 1):

> All you GET is 200 OK.

or may be some variations,

> All you GET is 200 SUCCESS.
>   All you GET is HTTP-200.
>   All you GET is HTTP-OK.

Comment: You are dangerously close to turning HTTP responses into a haiku. That's just awesome.

Comment: @Tim "teh DOM" (rimshot)

Answer (score 1):

Destroying botnets through education since 2010 ...

Answer (score 0):

> Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: This question is 4 years old but I couldn't resist ;)