# Help Pinocchio Become A Real Boy!

Tags: discussion, beta-progress

Pro Webmasters needs your help in order to grow and become an official Stack Exchange web site in:

**[43 Days](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/894/pro-webmasters)**

Here are some things that you can do to help us reach that goal:

- Answer some [unanswered questions](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/unanswered). We already have a high percentage of answered questions, but we want to make sure that everyone gets an answer. If you look at the [list of Stack Exchange sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites), you'll see how this number will influence our success.
- Market this web site via Twitter, Facebook, Link shares and even on your own web sites where possible. If we pick up the traffic a bit and continue with a > 95% answer rate, we will be one step closer to our goal.
- Spend some time voting on questions and answers. This helps to ensure that new users see the best that we have to offer and a very active community.
- If you operate a blog where a mention of Pro Webmasters would be on topic, consider writing a few paragraphs to explain why the site is a great resource to anyone who operates web sites.
- If you are graphically inclined (or know someone who is), try making some promotional materials like standard size banners. Very soon, Stack Exchange is going to help us market ourselves, but we don't have to wait for them. There are [several](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62/we-need-a-site-slogan) [discussions](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159/final-design-look-of-the-site) [related](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18/what-do-you-want-our-final-domain-name-to-be) to this that could really use more input.

Please feel free to answer with more ideas on how we can become a *real* site, and [always let your conscious be your guide](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DOZzNOkcEgM)!

Please do ***not*** use any official trademarks without permission in any materials that you post here or on other sites. This includes Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange.

<sub>Explanation of the [Pinocchio reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinocchio)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

When i got time i can do some PR material. And many of my co-workers are graphic designers. So i think we can do something for the community. :-)

Comment: @faw that's great!